# Javascript Wikipedia Summary Extraction error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia-api

I am trying to pull off data from Wikipedia using the API.

Here is the snap of the initial code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var searchTerm = document.title;
  $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=" + searchTerm + '&prop=text&format=json&callback=?', function(json) {
    $('#wikiInfo').html(json.parse.text['*']);
    $("#wikiInfo").find("a:not(.references a)").attr("href", function() {
      return "http://www.wikipedia.org" + $(this).attr("href");
    });
    $("#wikiInfo").find("a").attr("target", "_blank");
  });
});
```

```html
<title>Fire</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wikiInfo"> &nbsp; </div>
```

However, this gives me the entire page and I am looking for something that will give me just the summary of the Wiki page.
I looked online and the solution suggested was to change some of the initial parameters and make the JS look like :

```js
var searchTerm =  document.title;
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&titles=" +searchTerm +'&callback=?', function(json) { 
    $('#wikiInfo').html(json.parse.text['*']); 
    $("#wikiInfo").find("a:not(.references a)").attr("href", function(){ return "http://www.wikipedia.org" + $(this).attr("href");}); 
    $("#wikiInfo").find("a").attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

However, now I face the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at Object.success (wikis.html:9)
    at c (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:3)
    at k (jquery.min.js:5)
    at HTMLScriptElement.n.onload.n.onreadystatechange (jquery.min.js:5)
```

Could someone please help me out with what needs to be changed exactly? I am new to handling JSON data and using APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the page extract for the summary. The only downside is that extract is plain-text.

I turned some of your code at the end into jQuery plugins for easy reuse.

```js
var apiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';

(function($) {
  $.fn.fixWikiLinks = function() {
    this.find('a:not(.references a)').attr('href', function() {
      return 'http://www.wikipedia.org' + $(this).attr('href');
    });
    return this;
  };
  $.fn.setAnchorTargetsBlank = function() {
    this.find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var searchTerm = document.title;
  var params = {
    "format"      : "json",
    "action"      : "query",
    "prop"        : "extracts",
    "exintro"     : null,
    "explaintext" : null,
    "titles"      : searchTerm,
    "callback"    : "?"
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: apiUrl + '?' + $.param(params),
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
      var pages = json['query']['pages'];
      var pageIds = Object.keys(pages);

      if (pageIds.length > 0) {
        var initialPageId = pageIds[0];
        var page = pages[initialPageId]; // Get first page.
        var extract = page['extract'];

        $('#wikiInfo').html(extract).fixWikiLinks().setAnchorTargetsBlank();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<title>Fire</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wikiInfo"> &nbsp; </div>
```